# How To Predict Loss Of Precision For Decimal Operations?

Tags: apex, rounding

How can I predict loss of precision for decimal operations?

For example in the below calculation the result is off by .00000000000002

Should I be rounding after each decimal operation?

```
Decimal d1 = 56.67;
System.debug(d1); // 56.67
Decimal d2 = 123.00;
System.debug(d2); // 123.0
System.debug(d1 + d2); // 179.67000000000002
```

Comment: I'm not getting that result with Decimal, but I am with Double. Are you sure Decimal is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to brush up on [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) (or just use Decimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Double, which means Double Float (twice as many bits as a Float), you'll be subject to IEEE 754 floating point errors. As a result, you should always make sure that you use Decimal, which has much greater internal precision ("arbitrary precision number", as it says [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)). Doubles require significantly less amount of internal storage on the heap, but can't faithfully reproduce arbitrary floating point values the way Decimal can. If I remember correctly, Decimal uses about 28 bytes of heap while a Double uses a mere 12.

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb is that if your business logic requires control over the handling of rounding - e.g. you are dealing with calculations about money where rounding rules need to be determinate - use [Decimal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm).

Decimal holds the individual digits in an internal array to ensure that numbers with any number of digits are preserved exactly. (See e.g. [Floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) for how Float/Double represents numbers. Float is good for preserving about 7 decimal digits and Double for preserving about 16 decimal digits.) Decimal also includes methods like:

```
divide(divisor, scale, roundingMode)
```

where you can tie down exactly what happens when e.g. `1 / 3` is calculated as far as the number of decimal places is concerned and what rounding algorithm is applied.

Decimal uses more heap space and implements its operations in software rather than in hardware. So it is much bigger and much slower than using Float or Double. But the vast majority of Apex code is only manipulating a few numbers so these differences have no significance.